# File Name Patterns and File Sets clashing with .hgignore in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have the following on `.hgignore`:

```
syntax: glob
*
```

and the following on `myfiles.txt`:

```
.zshrc                                                                                                                                     
.zprofile                                                                                                                                  
glob:.less*                                                                                                                                
glob:.emacs*/**                                                                                                                            
glob:src*/**                                                                                                                               
glob:.bash*                                                                                                                                
.inputrc                                                                                                                                   
.ssh
```

If I try adding the files in `myfiles.txt` to the Mercurial repository using [File Name patterns](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#patterns):

```
hg add listfile:myfiles.txt
```

or [File Sets](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#filesets):

```
hg add "set: 'listfile:myfiles.txt' "
```

it doesn't work; Mercurial prints nothing and it doesn't add any files.

However, the two statements above work as soon as I remove `*` from `.hgignore`, which is odd, since I thought an explicit `hg add` should override anything on `.hgignore`.

### Goal:

Aside from whether or not the above is expected Mercurial behavior, my goal is to have Mercurial ignore all files except those that I add explicitly from a control file such as `myfiles.txt` where I can use glob patterns. Is there a way to do this in Mercurial?

### Update:

I'm not sure why some of the file patterns work for @smooth reggae. As @Martin said below, he was able to reproduce the behavior above, where file patterns seem to "clash" `.hgignore`, as they do for me (i.e. Mercurial respects `.hgignore` regardless of the explit `hg add` command).

To clarify, I am running Mercurial version **2.0.1** on Linux, and I have tried this on Red Hat and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

@intrpc, I am using TortoiseHg 2.1.3/Mercurial 1.9.2 and I was able to get a similar sample to work: I had a file called `.sample` and another file two levels deep `foo/bar/Foo.txt`; I had `patterns.txt` located a level above. With the same `.hgignore` as yours, I ran `hg init` and then `hg add listfile:..\patterns-for-hg.txt` for two cases:

1. with the `patterns.txt` containing

   ```
   .sample
   glob:foo/**
   ```

   in this case, `hg status` told me that Mercurial had added `.sample` to the repository but skipped `foo/bar/Foo.txt`
2. with the `patterns.txt` containing

   ```
   .sample
   path:foo/bar/Foo.txt
   ```

   in this case, `hg status` told me that Mercurial had added both `.sample` and `foo/bar/Foo.txt`to the repository

The behaviour in (2) above seems to make sense to me, because, Mercurial will ignore `.hgignore` if you invoke `hg add` with a full path to the file (this is the "explicit add" you are referring to).

The only explanation I can think of for the behaviour in (1) is that the glob in `patterns.txt` is treated like a wildcard and not an exact pattern; hence, `hg add` respects `.hgignore` and exact paths (`.sample`) and nothing else.

These are, of course, guesses; so any response from someone more qualified is more welcome.

Comment: You are correct — I checked the source and patterns do indeed respect the `.hgignore` file. This is a little unfortunate and I'll raise the question on the Mercurial mailinglist.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I'm wondering why it works for smooth reggae. I did more tests and yes, as you said, patterns seem to respect my `.hgignore`.

Comment: @intrpc It doesn't work for him, glob patterns are also skipped for him.

Comment: Hi @MartinGeisler, I was wondering if you knew if there has been any progress on this. Perhaps a link to a discussion, ticket, issue, or bug that I can track?

Comment: @roseck: I forgot to post the link to the tiny discussion here:  http://mercurial.markmail.org/message/pixmtoxfqaxtreod I'm afraid nothing came out of it, so I suggest you follow up on the discussion yourself. You can just post to mercurial@selenic.com.